# Bootstrap datepicker inside table cell not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the bootstrap datepicker and it is rendering fine except in table cells, like you can see in the picture below. Does anyone know how this can  be fixed?

[image: datepicker not shown properly]

```
<td>
   <div class="input-group date" id="gebdatum">
      <div class="input-group-prepend datepickerbutton">
         <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input id="@Html.IdFor(model => model.GeboortedatumFormatted)" 
          name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.GeboortedatumFormatted)" 
          type="text" 
          value="@Model.GeboortedatumFormatted" 
          class="form-control" 
          autocomplete="off"/>
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GeboortedatumFormatted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Did you apply any custom css to this datepicker?, other than what bootstrap puts on it

Comment: Not that I know of, I was thinking there might be some css from the table applied to it. But it's hard to say as I can't inspect the datepicker element because it disappears when you click away.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the property debug: true to your config the picker stays open, allowing you to inspect the element and override the css properties causing the bad rendering.